# Cordova Chrome OS switch from tablet to laptop mode?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-os

Is there an event I can listen to, to know when the user changes the device from tablet mode (flip laptops) and back to laptop mode?
Reason I'm asking is, in the webview, the input will change from mousedown to touchstart in a Cordova app running on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The key is to always listen to the mousedown event and not the touchstart event. ChromeOS/Webview will trigger mousedown on touch  or on mouse down.

Comment: hey, did you find any listener or solution to detect Chromebook is changing its mode to tablet or vice versa?